# Angular 2 [ngSwitchCase] cannot support negative value?

Tags: angular, switch-statement

Commenting out the `<span *ngSwitchCase="-1">&darr;</span>` returns no error

```
<span class="pull-left ranking-movement" [ngSwitch]="profile.rankingMovement">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="1">&uarr;</span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="0">&#9472;</span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="-1">&darr;</span>
</span>
```

Is negative number not supported for `ngSwitchCase`?

Errors are as followings:

```
main.js?v1:23062 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 1, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 15 in [ngSwitchCase -1] in MainComponent@93:42 ("                   <span *ngSwitchCase="0">&#9472;</span>
                                    <span [ERROR ->]*ngSwitchCase="-1">&darr;</span>
                                </span>
                            "): MainComponent@93:42
Parser Error: Unexpected token 1, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 15 in [ngSwitchCase -1] in MainComponent@93:42
```

I am using RC.6

Comment: What error do you get if you don't comment it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why this is not supported but you can work around with

```
<span *ngSwitchCase="0 - 1">&darr;</span>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognize a string starting with `-` as expression. I'd consider it a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Using Angular 2.2.0-rc.0 (2016-11-02), I faced the same issue.

I personnaly fixed it with this :

```html
<div *ngSwitchCase="'-1'"></div>
```

By the way, this kind of mistake can raise others errors which seem unrelated (for me it was : **Expression has changed after it was checked**) while mixing NgSwich and NgFor.

PS : I would like to comment the Günter Zöchbauer answer, but I couldn't due to the lack of reputation points.